# paho.mqtt.Client won't hold a connection to MQTT

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I am trying to connect to an MQTT endpoint on AWS iot-core, but the connection won't go through and the on_connect function is never invoked.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt_client
from config import MQTT, TOPIC, DEVICE_ID, PREFIX, ENDPOINT, ROOTCERT, PORT, PROTOCOL
import time
import json
import ssl


class MyMQTTClient(mqtt_client.Client):

    def __init__(self, clientId: str):
        super().__init__(clientId, True, None, mqtt_client.MQTTv31)

    def connect(self):
        ret = super().connect(ENDPOINT, port=PORT)
        print("Connect attempt: ", ret)
        return ret

def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print("log: ", buf)

def on_connect(client: MyMQTTClient, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("publishing ")
    payload = {
      "bot_info": [], 
      "timestamp": int(time.time())
    }
    result = client.publish(PREFIX + "/" + DEVICE_ID + "/" + "opState", json.dumps(payload))
    result.wait_for_publish()

def on_disconnect(client: MyMQTTClient, userdata, rc):
    print("Disconnected")

def on_message(client: MyMQTTClient, userdata, message):
    print("Message received: " + message)

mqtt = MyMQTTClient("test_mqtt_client")


mqtt.on_message=on_message
mqtt.on_connect=on_connect
mqtt.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
mqtt.on_log = on_log
mqtt.tls_set(ca_certs="./certs/cacert.pem", certfile="./certs/certfile.crt", keyfile="./certs/keyfile.key", cert_reqs=1)
mqtt.connect() 
mqtt.loop_forever()
```

When I run the above code the result is:

```
Connect attempt:  0
Disconnected
log:  Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'test_mqtt_client'
Disconnected
log:  Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'test_mqtt_client'
Disconnected
log:  Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'test_mqtt_client'
Disconnected
log:  Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'test_mqtt_client'
Disconnected
log:  Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'test_mqtt_client'
Disconnected
log:  Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'test_mqtt_client'
Disconnected
log:  Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'test_mqtt_client'
Disconnected
log:  Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'test_mqtt_client'
Disconnected
log:  Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'test_mqtt_client'
Disconnected
log:  Sending CONNECT (u0, p0, wr0, wq0, wf0, c1, k60) client_id=b'test_mqtt_client'
Disconnected
```

As you can see, the client keeps trying to connect, but disconnects immediately without calling on_connect.  I am very confident that the certs are correct.  Is there a good way to debug this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `on_error` callback and also printing out the `rc` value in the `on_disconnect` callback to get the reason code?

Comment: Added an on_disconnect and the return code is a 7, but I can't find what that actually means anywhere